# How to implement server side pagination in Ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular, angular7, ng2-smart-table

I have created a new custom data source which extends the local Data Source. So that I am able to get all the records in the database. But that's not the case, because I have a thousand records in my database. So the above implementation is not efficient.

Now I tried to implement the server side pagination to it. I have gone through the GitHub ng2-smart-table issues(https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/30). But I couldn't find the correct solution to it. So could you please help with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which database are you using?  what have you already tried?  any code?

Comment: This is my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669968/ng2-smart-table-with-paging-from-back-end-spring/55606968#55606968

Comment: anyone here pls help me out with this question I too have a scenario where I need to change my component to server-side pagination, unable to find the solution pls help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for server side pagination

[ng2-smart-table with paging from back-end (Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669968/ng2-smart-table-with-paging-from-back-end-spring/55606968#55606968)

I have a filter which contains startIndex and recordCount information.
You should make sure that you only return requested amount of data from your API/DB/etc.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution..

1. Return your data from the DB or API like this.

```js
data: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}] total: 10
```

2. Fetch the data like this while specifying the datakey and totalkey names exactly how they were returned in the 1st step.

```js
return new ServerDataSource(this.http, {
  endPoint: endpointUrl,
  dataKey: 'data',
  totalKey: 'total',
});
```

3. In your table settings, show pager and set perPage < expected total for the paginator shows up.

```js
settings = {
  pager: {
    display: true,
    perPage: 5,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your database will probably support something like skip/limit functionality.  based on this the client code can make requests to the database in order to return partial results.

Comment: I am using mysql databse. so i can do skip/limit functioality. But my problem is to implement the same functionality in the ng2-smart-table. Because i have written my own DataSource which extends the LocalDataSource for it as i mentioned above github link. But i couldn't figure it out, how he has done the pagination.